# XML How to order elements in C# from dataset

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, dataset

At first sorry for my english, i'm french.
So, actually i'm creating an XML file from a dataset in SQL-Server, and with a XSD file.
I have a problem, when i generate the XML file, i don't know how to generate the elements and node in the right order, from the XSD file.
Did you have already meet the problem, and somebody have a solution for me?
Thanks a lot, see u everyone.

Comment: Post some code or elements you have to put in xml file.

Comment: C# DataSet will create schema and content (each *stand-alone* or combined as one) natively. You can write a DataSet's content out and/or read an existing XML (with or without schema). No need to code this yourself... Read about `ReadXML` and `WriteXML`...